# Finding Moments of Brownian Motion

Tags: brownian-motion

> I am trying to calculate the K-th moment for Standard Brownian Motion:
> $$Z(t) \sim N(0,t)$$

I'm given that the second moment is $t$, but I'm having trouble seeing how that was arrived at.

I thought to use $M_X(t) = E[e^{tX}] = e^{\mu t +\frac{1}{2} \sigma^2t^2}$, but had no luck.

Ultimately, I have to repeat the process for Arithmetic and Geometric Brownian Motion as well. So some pointers there would be helpful too.

Comment: It is easier to compute it for $N(0,1)$, and then note that if the $k$th moment of $N(0,1)$ is $m_k$ then the $k$th moment of $N(0,t)$ is $m_k t^{k/2}$, just by scaling. To compute it for $N(0,1)$, just repeatedly integrate by parts.

Answer (score 0):

For geometric Brownian motion, just set $t=k$ in the MGF.

For arithmetic, you integrate against the standard normal to get moments of $N(0,1).$ Scale by $t^{1/2}$ to get moments of $W_t.$

So we have
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int x^{k} e^{-x^2/2} dx = 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int x^{k-1} \; xe^{-x^2/2} \; dx  
$$
and integrate by parts.